# Lord Krishna and Satyabhama

Tags: mahabharata

How did Lord Krishna teach a lesson to Satyabhāma to get rid of her ego? What was the plan he put into action?

Comment: Are you talking about story of the dispute between Rukmini and Satyabhama involving the Parijata tree?  I don't think it's ever mentioned in Hindu scripture.

Comment: Again as in the case of Balarama, being the incarnation of Bhudevi and amsa of Mahalakshmi, Devi Satyabhama doesn't get ego. It's all just divine play. But maybe the incident of Tulabharam can be cited as an example of their leela.

Comment: @Keshav Satyabhama and Rukmini's dispute is found in Harivamsa. In fact it's one of the reasons stated as to why Krsna went to Svarga to retrieve the Parijata (as an extension of Satyabhama's desire to own the tree).

Comment: @Surya Oh ok, I didn't know about the Harivamsa's account of the story: http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_065.html

Comment: @KS--It is not about parijatha tree. It is the ego that got rid off.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan What story are you referring to other than the Parijata story?

Comment: @Parthasarathy Raghavan and Keshav - I have removed the down votes on the questions.

Comment: @krishna--You need not remove downvotes. It is a failure for me.

Comment: @Krishna--give ur mail id-- I want to  send the homam photos to u.

Comment: @keshav--Did you see the homam photos? I have sent a long back. Why no reply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hanuman came to see Lord Krishna. But he wanted to see as Lord Rama. Krishna thought that this is the time to teach satyabama a lesson to get rid of her ego. Satyabama thought she is handsome and intelligent. Krishna asked her to come like Sita devi. Immediately she wore jewels and silk saree and came. Krishna laughed and sent her back. Again he called. She came with uncombed hair without jewels and a crying face. Krishna laughed again and asked Rukmani to come like Sita. Rukmani came like the sita who was in the ashoka vanam [jungle];with a calm face clad in a ordinary saree with a thoughtful and polite smile on her face without jewels. Krishna immediately turned to Rama and asked Hanuman to have a darshan. Hanuman came and fell at Rama and Sita's feet [it was Krishna and Rukmani]. By seeing this satyabama's ego got rid off her.
>   **Source  Kodayin Paadhai by Mukkur Lakhsmi narasimhachar a great Vedanta scholar and done many yagnas. A disciple of Lord Narasimha.**

Answer (score 0):

> Satyabhama is the only child of the Yadava chief Satrajit. Even though
>   at the time it was more common to raise boys in martial arts and
>   athletic pursuits the Bhagavatam Puranas teach an important lesson in
>   equality with the introduction of Satyabhama in Krishna’s past times.
>   Satyabhama was haughty and high-spirited and had very little interest
>   in men until she met Krishna. Unlike his other wives who were
>   satisfied to stay at home, Satyabhama demanded to accompany Krishna as
>   a help mate in all fields, including warfare, for which her father had
>   given her ample training. Krishna did not tell her “no” go  home and
>   be a good little wife. This makes  a lot of sense to those who read
>   the past times of Lord Krishna in their entirety instead of taking
>   bits and pieces out of context to fit an agenda since he is constantly
>   trying to get it through people’s heads  that all are equal in
>   divinity.

[Full Story Source](http://www.hinduhumanrights.info/satyabhama-krishnas-warrior-wife/)

Comment: Answer from which source?? It is a comment only.

Comment: Parthasarathy Raghavan : i tried to post this as comment. But showing me that **Its too long by 294 characters**

Comment: @TC--Post it as two comments because  negative votes will be given  and your reputation points will go down. I faced initially these hurdles.

Comment: Parthasarathy Raghavan : Thanks, I will edit this answer.

Comment: @TC--welcome-- I gave you a suggestion to save your reputation points. Thx for understanding.

Comment: @TC--Kindly refer your clients for homams. Kindly refer my  profile. As you are a astrologer and vastu consultant you may have more contacts.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Please refer with full name. Don't use shortcuts. You should use @"followed by name". If not use @ firstname(no spaces). Users are only notified if use first name or full name.